# Flash ActiveX API documentation?

Tags: c#, winforms, flash, activex, quicktime

I am trying to put a Flash ActiveX control into a Windows Form but I am running into a problem: a lack of documentation.  The best I have found is a site called "F-IN-BOX" that has some documentation but much of the API is still a black box.  For example, some property will take an integer or a string and provide no clue about what it wants.  Another exanple is the FlashVersion() function that inexplicably returns 655361 on version 10.

Incidentally I'm having the same problem with Apple's Quicktime OCX.  I've searched both sites and Google and I'm starting to wonder if either of these companies provide documentation for any of their products.  Does anybody know where I can find documentation for either of them, even if it's the unofficial variety?

Comment: i'd like to extend the question to cover c++ as well. if any documentation on how to use flash activex object in c++, please go on and share

Answer (score 2):

Well once i worked with flash on a windows form, I took this example to get started, and the second link its a flash game being loaded to a winform

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/flashexternalapi.aspx

http://www.csharphelp.com/archives/files/archive81/cSharpFlash.zip

Hope this helps anyone, about documentation i didn't find any when working on that project i reached Adobe but i never got an answer from them :/

Alex

Answer (score 0):

[Adobe help](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cb0.html) take a look at this sample. It's very simple and nice to use.
You should stick with ExternalInterfaceProxy all time because it simplifies communication 100x times.